# What could cause an auto increment primary key to skip numbers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, auto-increment, identity, entity-framework

I have a  table created with the following T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I took a look at this table today and noticed the id column was skipping values:

> 1,
>   2,
>   3,
>   4,
>   5,
>   6,
>   7,
>   8,
>   9,
>   10,
>   11,
>   12,
>   13,
>   14,
>   15,
>   16,
>   17,
>   18,
>   19,
>   20,
>   21,
>   22,
>   23,
>   24,
>   25,
>   26,
>   27,
>   1027,
>   1028,
>   1029,
>   1030,
>   1031,
>   1032,
>   1033,
>   1034,
>   1035,
>   2034,
>   2035,
>   3034

I'm not worried about this or anything (my application doesn't care what the primary key is), I was just curious about what might cause this to occur. It does seem there's a sort of pattern, of jumping 1000 every time a "jump" happens.

My application using entity framework to insert these rows, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Just a brief time googling the entity framework piece can have an affect on the identify seed being altered/overwritten.

Comment: In EF are you using a connection string that includes `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName` settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many things that can cause gaps in an IDENTITY column (rollbacks, deletes), but in this case due to the jump I suspect it is this bug - caused by the changes to IDENTITY with the introduction of SEQUENCE:

- [Connect # 739013 : Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)

So I bet that if you look in SQL Server's error logs, the rows associated with these jumps were inserted shortly after a SQL Server service restart, a database was detached/re-attached, etc.

Really, though, why do you care about gaps? [You shouldn't](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43918/1186). If you need a contiguous sequence of numbers, stop using IDENTITY.

Comment: Like I said, I **don't** care about the gaps. I was just curious as to what might be causing them :)

Comment: @Mansfield that's not just for you, but other readers too... since most people who notice this, complain about it, or search for it, *do* care about gaps and *do* expect IDENTITY to provide magical sequences.

Comment: Im one who cares ... What should I use to make a contiguous sequence of numbers?

Comment: @Steve You can use a serializable transaction to make the next row max(current id) + 1. But how are you going to prevent gaps? Never let anyone delete anything ever?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, never allow anyone to delete anything ever (Delete -
 Deny). Government auditors get very grump when they see gaps in the reporting record to the federal government. I tell them Z28gc2hvdmUgYSBmdWNraW5nIHJha2UgdXAgdGhlaXIgZ29kIGRhbW5lZCBhc3Nlcw== that it's a limitation of the system, that nobody is able to delete rows, and if there was ever any delete: it would be logged with the `DELETE TRIGGER`. Now if we can just have SQL Server work gooder.

Comment: @IanBoyd You can still have rollbacks, how do you plan to handle those? Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

When inserts are rolled back, the identity values are NOT reset.  This is one explanation of the so called "skipped" values.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. I can't think of too many situations wherein that would have happened here though; and definitely not in the order of a thousand times...

Comment: @Mansfield that's **one** reason. There are several others and some depend on version. SQL-Server 2012 is known to have these 1000 or bigger gaps: [Connect item: Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)

Comment: Related connect item on gaps: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer might be late. Yes, this used to happen when SQL server is restarted. See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity) for more information (as given in other answers). With SQL Server 2014, it has been fixed (identity wont increased by 1000) only if there was a planned SQL Server restart.

I have solved in another way by adding a start up stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

Create a following stored procedure in master DB.

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResetOrderIdentityAfterRestart]
AS
BEGIN

begin TRAN
    declare @id int = 0
    SELECT @id =  MAX(id) FROM [DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]
    --print @id
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]', reseed, @id)
Commit

END
```

Then add it in to Start up by using following syntax.

```
EXEC sp_procoption 'ResetOrderIdentityAfterRestart', 'startup', 'on';
```

This is a good idea if you have few tables. but if you have to do for many tables, this method still works but not a good idea.